# Add the individual numbers of a date

Tags: java, python

I did look for something but couldn't successfully find a solution.

Is there a way to find the sum of the numbers of a date.
For example: if the date is `2016-03-14` I want to add up all the digits to get the total of `17`.

I would really appreciate if I can get an answer in either python or java (I know this is weird request but personally I love to use python but professionally I use java hence, knowing this information both languages would be really beneficial to me.)

Edit_1: I have to iterate over a specific number of days (includes date, month, year) and add the individual digits of the date to get the sum.

Comment: Just iterate the digits and add them is they are digits?

Comment: the date is a `Date` object or a `String`?

Comment: @Maljam. It is a `Date` object. I have to iterate over a specific number of dates and get the sum.

Answer (score 2):

Java:

```
int total = 0;
String str = date.toString();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
  if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
    total += Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i));
  }
}
```

Python:

```
total = 0
string = str(date)
for c in string:
  if c.isdigit():
    total += int(c)
```

or, as a list comprehension:

```
sum([int(c) for c in str(date) if c.isdigit()])
```

Comment: it is not a string. I am using the `datetime` in python as I have to iterate over a few days.

Comment: Convert it to a string then, using `str(date)`, as in the answer.

Comment: yes will do that. and because the answer was easy I am going to delete this question.

Comment: You've got many answers, as several people have invested effort in solving your problem. Pay it back by leaving the question here and upvoting (and accepting the answer which works best for you).

Comment: I know I am sounding stupid right now but I changed my mind and I won't delete it.

Comment: Your Python is... odd. `isdigit` is not a builtin, so it should be `c.isdigit()` instead of `isdigit(c)`. And `where` is not a keyword in Python, it should be `sum(int(c) for c in str(date) if c.isdigit())`

Comment: @tobias_k let's call it rusty rather than odd :) Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.
Something like:

```
int sum = getDigits(date.get("YEAR")) + getDigits(date.get("MONTH")) + getDigits(date.get("DAY_OF_MONTH"));

public int getDigits(int num) {
int sum = 0;
while (num > 0) {
    sum = sum + num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
}
return sum;
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's for Calendar object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to do it but here is a simple way of doing it in JAVA by using and iterating the char array.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    String date = "2016-03-14";
    char[] input = date.toCharArray();
    int sum = 0;
    for(char c : input) {
        if((int)(c - '0') >= 0 && (int)(c - '0') <=9)
            sum += (int)(c - '0');
    }
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
}
```

Output:

```
Sum: 17
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do something like:

```
int sum = 0;
for(char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if( Character.isDigit(c) ) sum += (c-'0'); 
}
```

And if your date is a `Date` object:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int year = date.getYear() ; year > 0 ; year /= 10) sum += year%10;
for(int month = date.getMonth() ; month > 0 ; month /= 10) sum += month%10;
for(int date = date.getDate() ; date > 0 ; date /= 10) sum += date%10;
```